# Explain this strange phenomenon with space

Tags: java, unicode, whitespace

Here is the code:

```
public class printuni{
 public static void main(String[] args){
     int a;
     char c;
     for(a=1400;a<=1900;a++){
        c = (char)a ;
        System.out.println("  integer " + a + " = " + c);
        }   
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
  integer 1400 = ո
  integer 1401 = չ
  integer 1402 = պ
  integer 1403 = ջ
  integer 1404 = ռ
  integer 1405 = ս
  integer 1406 = վ
  integer 1407 = տ
  integer 1408 = ր
  integer 1409 = ց
  integer 1410 = ւ
  integer 1411 = փ
  integer 1412 = ք
  integer 1413 = օ
  integer 1414 = ֆ
  integer 1415 = և
  integer 1416 = ֈ
  integer 1417 = ։
  integer 1418 = ֊
  integer 1419 = ֋
  integer 1420 = ֌
  integer 1421 = ֍
  integer 1422 = ֎
  integer 1423 = ֏
  integer 1424 = ֐
  integer 1425 = ֑
  integer 1426 = ֒
  integer 1427 = ֓
  integer 1428 = ֔
  integer 1429 = ֕
  integer 1430 = ֖
  integer 1431 = ֗
  integer 1432 = ֘
  integer 1433 = ֙
  integer 1434 = ֚
  integer 1435 = ֛
  integer 1436 = ֜
  integer 1437 = ֝
  integer 1438 = ֞
  integer 1439 = ֟
  integer 1440 = ֠
  integer 1441 = ֡
  integer 1442 = ֢
  integer 1443 = ֣
  integer 1444 = ֤
  integer 1445 = ֥
  integer 1446 = ֦
  integer 1447 = ֧
  integer 1448 = ֨
  integer 1449 = ֩
  integer 1450 = ֪
  integer 1451 = ֫
  integer 1452 = ֬
  integer 1453 = ֭
  integer 1454 = ֮
  integer 1455 = ֯
  integer 1456 = ְ
  integer 1457 = ֱ
  integer 1458 = ֲ
  integer 1459 = ֳ
  integer 1460 = ִ
  integer 1461 = ֵ
  integer 1462 = ֶ
  integer 1463 = ַ
  integer 1464 = ָ
  integer 1465 = ֹ
  integer 1466 = ֺ
  integer 1467 = ֻ
  integer 1468 = ּ
  integer 1469 = ֽ
  integer 1470 = ־
  integer 1471 = ֿ
  integer 1472 = ׀
  integer 1473 = ׁ
  integer 1474 = ׂ
  integer 1475 = ׃
  integer 1476 = ׄ
  integer 1477 = ׅ
  integer 1478 = ׆
  integer 1479 = ׇ
  integer 1480 = ׈
  integer 1481 = ׉
  integer 1482 = ׊
  integer 1483 = ׋
  integer 1484 = ׌
  integer 1485 = ׍
  integer 1486 = ׎
  integer 1487 = ׏
  integer 1488 = א
  integer 1489 = ב
  integer 1490 = ג
  integer 1491 = ד
  integer 1492 = ה
  integer 1493 = ו
  integer 1494 = ז
  integer 1495 = ח
  integer 1496 = ט
  integer 1497 = י
  integer 1498 = ך
  integer 1499 = כ
  integer 1500 = ל
  integer 1501 = ם
  integer 1502 = מ
  integer 1503 = ן
  integer 1504 = נ
  integer 1505 = ס
  integer 1506 = ע
  integer 1507 = ף
  integer 1508 = פ
  integer 1509 = ץ
  integer 1510 = צ
  integer 1511 = ק
  integer 1512 = ר
  integer 1513 = ש
  integer 1514 = ת
  integer 1515 = ׫
  integer 1516 = ׬
  integer 1517 = ׭
  integer 1518 = ׮
  integer 1519 = ׯ
  integer 1520 = װ
  integer 1521 = ױ
  integer 1522 = ײ
  integer 1523 = ׳
  integer 1524 = ״
  integer 1525 = ׵
  integer 1526 = ׶
  integer 1527 = ׷
  integer 1528 = ׸
  integer 1529 = ׹
  integer 1530 = ׺
  integer 1531 = ׻
  integer 1532 = ׼
  integer 1533 = ׽
  integer 1534 = ׾
  integer 1535 = ׿
  integer 1536 = ؀
  integer 1537 = ؁
  integer 1538 = ؂
  integer 1539 = ؃
  integer 1540 = ؄
  integer 1541 = ؅
  integer 1542 = ؆
  integer 1543 = ؇
  integer 1544 = ؈
  integer 1545 = ؉
  integer 1546 = ؊
  integer 1547 = ؋
  integer 1548 = ،
  integer 1549 = ؍
  integer 1550 = ؎
  integer 1551 = ؏
  integer 1552 = ؐ
  integer 1553 = ؑ
  integer 1554 = ؒ
  integer 1555 = ؓ
  integer 1556 = ؔ
  integer 1557 = ؕ
  integer 1558 = ؖ
  integer 1559 = ؗ
  integer 1560 = ؘ
  integer 1561 = ؙ
  integer 1562 = ؚ
  integer 1563 = ؛
  integer 1564 = ؜
  integer 1565 = ؝
  integer 1566 = ؞
  integer 1567 = ؟
  integer 1568 = ؠ
  integer 1569 = ء
  integer 1570 = آ
  integer 1571 = أ
  integer 1572 = ؤ
  integer 1573 = إ
  integer 1574 = ئ
  integer 1575 = ا
  integer 1576 = ب
  integer 1577 = ة
  integer 1578 = ت
  integer 1579 = ث
  integer 1580 = ج
  integer 1581 = ح
  integer 1582 = خ
  integer 1583 = د
  integer 1584 = ذ
  integer 1585 = ر
  integer 1586 = ز
  integer 1587 = س
  integer 1588 = ش
  integer 1589 = ص
  integer 1590 = ض
  integer 1591 = ط
  integer 1592 = ظ
  integer 1593 = ع
  integer 1594 = غ
  integer 1595 = ػ
  integer 1596 = ؼ
  integer 1597 = ؽ
  integer 1598 = ؾ
  integer 1599 = ؿ
  integer 1600 = ـ
  integer 1601 = ف
  integer 1602 = ق
  integer 1603 = ك
  integer 1604 = ل
  integer 1605 = م
  integer 1606 = ن
  integer 1607 = ه
  integer 1608 = و
  integer 1609 = ى
  integer 1610 = ي
  integer 1611 = ً
  integer 1612 = ٌ
  integer 1613 = ٍ
  integer 1614 = َ
  integer 1615 = ُ
  integer 1616 = ِ
  integer 1617 = ّ
  integer 1618 = ْ
  integer 1619 = ٓ
  integer 1620 = ٔ
  integer 1621 = ٕ
  integer 1622 = ٖ
  integer 1623 = ٗ
  integer 1624 = ٘
  integer 1625 = ٙ
  integer 1626 = ٚ
  integer 1627 = ٛ
  integer 1628 = ٜ
  integer 1629 = ٝ
  integer 1630 = ٞ
  integer 1631 = ٟ
  integer 1632 = ٠
  integer 1633 = ١
  integer 1634 = ٢
  integer 1635 = ٣
  integer 1636 = ٤
  integer 1637 = ٥
  integer 1638 = ٦
  integer 1639 = ٧
  integer 1640 = ٨
  integer 1641 = ٩
  integer 1642 = ٪
  integer 1643 = ٫
  integer 1644 = ٬
  integer 1645 = ٭
  integer 1646 = ٮ
  integer 1647 = ٯ
  integer 1648 = ٰ
  integer 1649 = ٱ
  integer 1650 = ٲ
  integer 1651 = ٳ
  integer 1652 = ٴ
  integer 1653 = ٵ
  integer 1654 = ٶ
  integer 1655 = ٷ
  integer 1656 = ٸ
  integer 1657 = ٹ
  integer 1658 = ٺ
  integer 1659 = ٻ
  integer 1660 = ټ
  integer 1661 = ٽ
  integer 1662 = پ
  integer 1663 = ٿ
  integer 1664 = ڀ
  integer 1665 = ځ
  integer 1666 = ڂ
  integer 1667 = ڃ
  integer 1668 = ڄ
  integer 1669 = څ
  integer 1670 = چ
  integer 1671 = ڇ
  integer 1672 = ڈ
  integer 1673 = ډ
  integer 1674 = ڊ
  integer 1675 = ڋ
  integer 1676 = ڌ
  integer 1677 = ڍ
  integer 1678 = ڎ
  integer 1679 = ڏ
  integer 1680 = ڐ
  integer 1681 = ڑ
  integer 1682 = ڒ
  integer 1683 = ړ
  integer 1684 = ڔ
  integer 1685 = ڕ
  integer 1686 = ږ
  integer 1687 = ڗ
  integer 1688 = ژ
  integer 1689 = ڙ
  integer 1690 = ښ
  integer 1691 = ڛ
  integer 1692 = ڜ
  integer 1693 = ڝ
  integer 1694 = ڞ
  integer 1695 = ڟ
  integer 1696 = ڠ
  integer 1697 = ڡ
  integer 1698 = ڢ
  integer 1699 = ڣ
  integer 1700 = ڤ
  integer 1701 = ڥ
  integer 1702 = ڦ
  integer 1703 = ڧ
  integer 1704 = ڨ
  integer 1705 = ک
  integer 1706 = ڪ
  integer 1707 = ګ
  integer 1708 = ڬ
  integer 1709 = ڭ
  integer 1710 = ڮ
  integer 1711 = گ
  integer 1712 = ڰ
  integer 1713 = ڱ
  integer 1714 = ڲ
  integer 1715 = ڳ
  integer 1716 = ڴ
  integer 1717 = ڵ
  integer 1718 = ڶ
  integer 1719 = ڷ
  integer 1720 = ڸ
  integer 1721 = ڹ
  integer 1722 = ں
  integer 1723 = ڻ
  integer 1724 = ڼ
  integer 1725 = ڽ
  integer 1726 = ھ
  integer 1727 = ڿ
  integer 1728 = ۀ
  integer 1729 = ہ
  integer 1730 = ۂ
  integer 1731 = ۃ
  integer 1732 = ۄ
  integer 1733 = ۅ
  integer 1734 = ۆ
  integer 1735 = ۇ
  integer 1736 = ۈ
  integer 1737 = ۉ
  integer 1738 = ۊ
  integer 1739 = ۋ
  integer 1740 = ی
  integer 1741 = ۍ
  integer 1742 = ێ
  integer 1743 = ۏ
  integer 1744 = ې
  integer 1745 = ۑ
  integer 1746 = ے
  integer 1747 = ۓ
  integer 1748 = ۔
  integer 1749 = ە
  integer 1750 = ۖ
  integer 1751 = ۗ
  integer 1752 = ۘ
  integer 1753 = ۙ
  integer 1754 = ۚ
  integer 1755 = ۛ
  integer 1756 = ۜ
  integer 1757 = ۝
  integer 1758 = ۞
  integer 1759 = ۟
  integer 1760 = ۠
  integer 1761 = ۡ
  integer 1762 = ۢ
  integer 1763 = ۣ
  integer 1764 = ۤ
  integer 1765 = ۥ
  integer 1766 = ۦ
  integer 1767 = ۧ
  integer 1768 = ۨ
  integer 1769 = ۩
  integer 1770 = ۪
  integer 1771 = ۫
  integer 1772 = ۬
  integer 1773 = ۭ
  integer 1774 = ۮ
  integer 1775 = ۯ
  integer 1776 = ۰
  integer 1777 = ۱
  integer 1778 = ۲
  integer 1779 = ۳
  integer 1780 = ۴
  integer 1781 = ۵
  integer 1782 = ۶
  integer 1783 = ۷
  integer 1784 = ۸
  integer 1785 = ۹
  integer 1786 = ۺ
  integer 1787 = ۻ
  integer 1788 = ۼ
  integer 1789 = ۽
  integer 1790 = ۾
  integer 1791 = ۿ
  integer 1792 = ܀
  integer 1793 = ܁
  integer 1794 = ܂
  integer 1795 = ܃
  integer 1796 = ܄
  integer 1797 = ܅
  integer 1798 = ܆
  integer 1799 = ܇
  integer 1800 = ܈
  integer 1801 = ܉
  integer 1802 = ܊
  integer 1803 = ܋
  integer 1804 = ܌
  integer 1805 = ܍
  integer 1806 = ܎
  integer 1807 = ܏
  integer 1808 = ܐ
  integer 1809 = ܑ
  integer 1810 = ܒ
  integer 1811 = ܓ
  integer 1812 = ܔ
  integer 1813 = ܕ
  integer 1814 = ܖ
  integer 1815 = ܗ
  integer 1816 = ܘ
  integer 1817 = ܙ
  integer 1818 = ܚ
  integer 1819 = ܛ
  integer 1820 = ܜ
  integer 1821 = ܝ
  integer 1822 = ܞ
  integer 1823 = ܟ
  integer 1824 = ܠ
  integer 1825 = ܡ
  integer 1826 = ܢ
  integer 1827 = ܣ
  integer 1828 = ܤ
  integer 1829 = ܥ
  integer 1830 = ܦ
  integer 1831 = ܧ
  integer 1832 = ܨ
  integer 1833 = ܩ
  integer 1834 = ܪ
  integer 1835 = ܫ
  integer 1836 = ܬ
  integer 1837 = ܭ
  integer 1838 = ܮ
  integer 1839 = ܯ
  integer 1840 = ܰ
  integer 1841 = ܱ
  integer 1842 = ܲ
  integer 1843 = ܳ
  integer 1844 = ܴ
  integer 1845 = ܵ
  integer 1846 = ܶ
  integer 1847 = ܷ
  integer 1848 = ܸ
  integer 1849 = ܹ
  integer 1850 = ܺ
  integer 1851 = ܻ
  integer 1852 = ܼ
  integer 1853 = ܽ
  integer 1854 = ܾ
  integer 1855 = ܿ
  integer 1856 = ݀
  integer 1857 = ݁
  integer 1858 = ݂
  integer 1859 = ݃
  integer 1860 = ݄
  integer 1861 = ݅
  integer 1862 = ݆
  integer 1863 = ݇
  integer 1864 = ݈
  integer 1865 = ݉
  integer 1866 = ݊
  integer 1867 = ݋
  integer 1868 = ݌
  integer 1869 = ݍ
  integer 1870 = ݎ
  integer 1871 = ݏ
  integer 1872 = ݐ
  integer 1873 = ݑ
  integer 1874 = ݒ
  integer 1875 = ݓ
  integer 1876 = ݔ
  integer 1877 = ݕ
  integer 1878 = ݖ
  integer 1879 = ݗ
  integer 1880 = ݘ
  integer 1881 = ݙ
  integer 1882 = ݚ
  integer 1883 = ݛ
  integer 1884 = ݜ
  integer 1885 = ݝ
  integer 1886 = ݞ
  integer 1887 = ݟ
  integer 1888 = ݠ
  integer 1889 = ݡ
  integer 1890 = ݢ
  integer 1891 = ݣ
  integer 1892 = ݤ
  integer 1893 = ݥ
  integer 1894 = ݦ
  integer 1895 = ݧ
  integer 1896 = ݨ
  integer 1897 = ݩ
  integer 1898 = ݪ
  integer 1899 = ݫ
  integer 1900 = ݬ
```

The above code slightly modified:

```
public class printuni{
 public static void main(String[] args){
     int a;
     char c;
     for(a=1400;a<=1900;a++){
        c = (char)a ;
        System.out.println("  " + a + " = " + c);
     }   
 }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
  1400 = ո
  1401 = չ
  1402 = պ
  1403 = ջ
  1404 = ռ
  1405 = ս
  1406 = վ
  1407 = տ
  1408 = ր
  1409 = ց
  1410 = ւ
  1411 = փ
  1412 = ք
  1413 = օ
  1414 = ֆ
  1415 = և
  1416 = ֈ
  1417 = ։
  1418 = ֊
  1419 = ֋
  1420 = ֌
  1421 = ֍
  1422 = ֎
  1423 = ֏
  1424 = ֐
  1425 = ֑
  1426 = ֒
  1427 = ֓
  1428 = ֔
  1429 = ֕
  1430 = ֖
  1431 = ֗
  1432 = ֘
  1433 = ֙
  1434 = ֚
  1435 = ֛
  1436 = ֜
  1437 = ֝
  1438 = ֞
  1439 = ֟
  1440 = ֠
  1441 = ֡
  1442 = ֢
  1443 = ֣
  1444 = ֤
  1445 = ֥
  1446 = ֦
  1447 = ֧
  1448 = ֨
  1449 = ֩
  1450 = ֪
  1451 = ֫
  1452 = ֬
  1453 = ֭
  1454 = ֮
  1455 = ֯
  1456 = ְ
  1457 = ֱ
  1458 = ֲ
  1459 = ֳ
  1460 = ִ
  1461 = ֵ
  1462 = ֶ
  1463 = ַ
  1464 = ָ
  1465 = ֹ
  1466 = ֺ
  1467 = ֻ
  1468 = ּ
  1469 = ֽ
  1470 = ־
  1471 = ֿ
  1472 = ׀
  1473 = ׁ
  1474 = ׂ
  1475 = ׃
  1476 = ׄ
  1477 = ׅ
  1478 = ׆
  1479 = ׇ
  1480 = ׈
  1481 = ׉
  1482 = ׊
  1483 = ׋
  1484 = ׌
  1485 = ׍
  1486 = ׎
  1487 = ׏
  1488 = א
  1489 = ב
  1490 = ג
  1491 = ד
  1492 = ה
  1493 = ו
  1494 = ז
  1495 = ח
  1496 = ט
  1497 = י
  1498 = ך
  1499 = כ
  1500 = ל
  1501 = ם
  1502 = מ
  1503 = ן
  1504 = נ
  1505 = ס
  1506 = ע
  1507 = ף
  1508 = פ
  1509 = ץ
  1510 = צ
  1511 = ק
  1512 = ר
  1513 = ש
  1514 = ת
  1515 = ׫
  1516 = ׬
  1517 = ׭
  1518 = ׮
  1519 = ׯ
  1520 = װ
  1521 = ױ
  1522 = ײ
  1523 = ׳
  1524 = ״
  1525 = ׵
  1526 = ׶
  1527 = ׷
  1528 = ׸
  1529 = ׹
  1530 = ׺
  1531 = ׻
  1532 = ׼
  1533 = ׽
  1534 = ׾
  1535 = ׿
  1536 = ؀
  1537 = ؁
  1538 = ؂
  1539 = ؃
  1540 = ؄
  1541 = ؅
  1542 = ؆
  1543 = ؇
  1544 = ؈
  1545 = ؉
  1546 = ؊
  1547 = ؋
  1548 = ،
  1549 = ؍
  1550 = ؎
  1551 = ؏
  1552 = ؐ
  1553 = ؑ
  1554 = ؒ
  1555 = ؓ
  1556 = ؔ
  1557 = ؕ
  1558 = ؖ
  1559 = ؗ
  1560 = ؘ
  1561 = ؙ
  1562 = ؚ
  1563 = ؛
  1564 = ؜
  1565 = ؝
  1566 = ؞
  1567 = ؟
  1568 = ؠ
  1569 = ء
  1570 = آ
  1571 = أ
  1572 = ؤ
  1573 = إ
  1574 = ئ
  1575 = ا
  1576 = ب
  1577 = ة
  1578 = ت
  1579 = ث
  1580 = ج
  1581 = ح
  1582 = خ
  1583 = د
  1584 = ذ
  1585 = ر
  1586 = ز
  1587 = س
  1588 = ش
  1589 = ص
  1590 = ض
  1591 = ط
  1592 = ظ
  1593 = ع
  1594 = غ
  1595 = ػ
  1596 = ؼ
  1597 = ؽ
  1598 = ؾ
  1599 = ؿ
  1600 = ـ
  1601 = ف
  1602 = ق
  1603 = ك
  1604 = ل
  1605 = م
  1606 = ن
  1607 = ه
  1608 = و
  1609 = ى
  1610 = ي
  1611 = ً
  1612 = ٌ
  1613 = ٍ
  1614 = َ
  1615 = ُ
  1616 = ِ
  1617 = ّ
  1618 = ْ
  1619 = ٓ
  1620 = ٔ
  1621 = ٕ
  1622 = ٖ
  1623 = ٗ
  1624 = ٘
  1625 = ٙ
  1626 = ٚ
  1627 = ٛ
  1628 = ٜ
  1629 = ٝ
  1630 = ٞ
  1631 = ٟ
  1632 = ٠
  1633 = ١
  1634 = ٢
  1635 = ٣
  1636 = ٤
  1637 = ٥
  1638 = ٦
  1639 = ٧
  1640 = ٨
  1641 = ٩
  1642 = ٪
  1643 = ٫
  1644 = ٬
  1645 = ٭
  1646 = ٮ
  1647 = ٯ
  1648 = ٰ
  1649 = ٱ
  1650 = ٲ
  1651 = ٳ
  1652 = ٴ
  1653 = ٵ
  1654 = ٶ
  1655 = ٷ
  1656 = ٸ
  1657 = ٹ
  1658 = ٺ
  1659 = ٻ
  1660 = ټ
  1661 = ٽ
  1662 = پ
  1663 = ٿ
  1664 = ڀ
  1665 = ځ
  1666 = ڂ
  1667 = ڃ
  1668 = ڄ
  1669 = څ
  1670 = چ
  1671 = ڇ
  1672 = ڈ
  1673 = ډ
  1674 = ڊ
  1675 = ڋ
  1676 = ڌ
  1677 = ڍ
  1678 = ڎ
  1679 = ڏ
  1680 = ڐ
  1681 = ڑ
  1682 = ڒ
  1683 = ړ
  1684 = ڔ
  1685 = ڕ
  1686 = ږ
  1687 = ڗ
  1688 = ژ
  1689 = ڙ
  1690 = ښ
  1691 = ڛ
  1692 = ڜ
  1693 = ڝ
  1694 = ڞ
  1695 = ڟ
  1696 = ڠ
  1697 = ڡ
  1698 = ڢ
  1699 = ڣ
  1700 = ڤ
  1701 = ڥ
  1702 = ڦ
  1703 = ڧ
  1704 = ڨ
  1705 = ک
  1706 = ڪ
  1707 = ګ
  1708 = ڬ
  1709 = ڭ
  1710 = ڮ
  1711 = گ
  1712 = ڰ
  1713 = ڱ
  1714 = ڲ
  1715 = ڳ
  1716 = ڴ
  1717 = ڵ
  1718 = ڶ
  1719 = ڷ
  1720 = ڸ
  1721 = ڹ
  1722 = ں
  1723 = ڻ
  1724 = ڼ
  1725 = ڽ
  1726 = ھ
  1727 = ڿ
  1728 = ۀ
  1729 = ہ
  1730 = ۂ
  1731 = ۃ
  1732 = ۄ
  1733 = ۅ
  1734 = ۆ
  1735 = ۇ
  1736 = ۈ
  1737 = ۉ
  1738 = ۊ
  1739 = ۋ
  1740 = ی
  1741 = ۍ
  1742 = ێ
  1743 = ۏ
  1744 = ې
  1745 = ۑ
  1746 = ے
  1747 = ۓ
  1748 = ۔
  1749 = ە
  1750 = ۖ
  1751 = ۗ
  1752 = ۘ
  1753 = ۙ
  1754 = ۚ
  1755 = ۛ
  1756 = ۜ
  1757 = ۝
  1758 = ۞
  1759 = ۟
  1760 = ۠
  1761 = ۡ
  1762 = ۢ
  1763 = ۣ
  1764 = ۤ
  1765 = ۥ
  1766 = ۦ
  1767 = ۧ
  1768 = ۨ
  1769 = ۩
  1770 = ۪
  1771 = ۫
  1772 = ۬
  1773 = ۭ
  1774 = ۮ
  1775 = ۯ
  1776 = ۰
  1777 = ۱
  1778 = ۲
  1779 = ۳
  1780 = ۴
  1781 = ۵
  1782 = ۶
  1783 = ۷
  1784 = ۸
  1785 = ۹
  1786 = ۺ
  1787 = ۻ
  1788 = ۼ
  1789 = ۽
  1790 = ۾
  1791 = ۿ
  1792 = ܀
  1793 = ܁
  1794 = ܂
  1795 = ܃
  1796 = ܄
  1797 = ܅
  1798 = ܆
  1799 = ܇
  1800 = ܈
  1801 = ܉
  1802 = ܊
  1803 = ܋
  1804 = ܌
  1805 = ܍
  1806 = ܎
  1807 = ܏
  1808 = ܐ
  1809 = ܑ
  1810 = ܒ
  1811 = ܓ
  1812 = ܔ
  1813 = ܕ
  1814 = ܖ
  1815 = ܗ
  1816 = ܘ
  1817 = ܙ
  1818 = ܚ
  1819 = ܛ
  1820 = ܜ
  1821 = ܝ
  1822 = ܞ
  1823 = ܟ
  1824 = ܠ
  1825 = ܡ
  1826 = ܢ
  1827 = ܣ
  1828 = ܤ
  1829 = ܥ
  1830 = ܦ
  1831 = ܧ
  1832 = ܨ
  1833 = ܩ
  1834 = ܪ
  1835 = ܫ
  1836 = ܬ
  1837 = ܭ
  1838 = ܮ
  1839 = ܯ
  1840 = ܰ
  1841 = ܱ
  1842 = ܲ
  1843 = ܳ
  1844 = ܴ
  1845 = ܵ
  1846 = ܶ
  1847 = ܷ
  1848 = ܸ
  1849 = ܹ
  1850 = ܺ
  1851 = ܻ
  1852 = ܼ
  1853 = ܽ
  1854 = ܾ
  1855 = ܿ
  1856 = ݀
  1857 = ݁
  1858 = ݂
  1859 = ݃
  1860 = ݄
  1861 = ݅
  1862 = ݆
  1863 = ݇
  1864 = ݈
  1865 = ݉
  1866 = ݊
  1867 = ݋
  1868 = ݌
  1869 = ݍ
  1870 = ݎ
  1871 = ݏ
  1872 = ݐ
  1873 = ݑ
  1874 = ݒ
  1875 = ݓ
  1876 = ݔ
  1877 = ݕ
  1878 = ݖ
  1879 = ݗ
  1880 = ݘ
  1881 = ݙ
  1882 = ݚ
  1883 = ݛ
  1884 = ݜ
  1885 = ݝ
  1886 = ݞ
  1887 = ݟ
  1888 = ݠ
  1889 = ݡ
  1890 = ݢ
  1891 = ݣ
  1892 = ݤ
  1893 = ݥ
  1894 = ݦ
  1895 = ݧ
  1896 = ݨ
  1897 = ݩ
  1898 = ݪ
  1899 = ݫ
  1900 = ݬ
```

All I did was replace the "integer" with  "  ". I get this strange output where LHS and RHS have often got  reversed!

Comment: `I get this strange output where LHS and RHS have often got reversed!` Could you point out where this happens in the output snippets you posted? I'm afraid I'm not seeing it.

Comment: I think it's just your editor (or browser) chooses to show the lines in RTL/LTR fashion when latin chars ('integer') present. This occurs because some of the chars in the output are from RTL languages (Hebrew/Arabic).

Comment: The second output cannot possibly have been produced by the second snippet (1901 is included). What else is different from the shown snippet and what's actually run?

Comment: you can explore the [unicode map](http://www.unicodemap.org/range/12/Arabic/) to have an idea of what you are trying to print — as @vadchen suggests, since you are printing also chars of r2l languages, there could be context where the displayer "switch" to that mode, inferring it from the codes you are printing

Comment: @PakkuDon look at 1425 for example.

Comment: @vadchen what is RTL/LTR?

Comment: @user3015246 Right-To-Left or Left-To-Right, some editors decide to reverse string if they detect RTL language. In your case an editor reverses it only when there is RTL language but no LTR (english) in particular line.

Comment: @ShinTakezou what is r2l and why/how does it switch like that?

Comment: BTW: I too see two identical outputs here

Comment: @vadchen: I see. Thanks. But why does it not reverse it when I say "integer"? Is it because it is in english?

Comment: what two identical outputs?

Comment: @user3015246 i posted it as answer with more details

Comment: @user3015246 two outputs from the code are identical in my browser

Comment: @vadchen really? They are definitely different in my browser. I am using firefox.

Comment: @user3015246 yes, looks like it decides that english letter makes it LTR whether or not there is arabic/hebrew there

Comment: I see. So that's it. BTW, I am using BlueJ IDE and firefox browser.

Comment: @user3015246 r2l = RTL = right to left language. We are arguing that some displayer of the text, recognizing Hebrew/Arabic chars (Hebrew and Arabic are written from right to left), could change the direction they write text, so you see it "reversed".

Comment: @ShinTakezou Thanks for your answer. That makes it clear. The unicode map you posted leads me to another question. I will ask it soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-To-Left or Left-To-Right, some editors decide to reverse string if they detect RTL language. In your case an editor reverses it only when there is RTL language but no LTR (english) in particular line.

see explanation here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text